# using mono mac with xcode

Tags: c#, xcode, mono, monodevelop, monomac

I have installed MonoDevelop and Xcode 4.1. When I create a project and click on .xib file and build the project in Xcode I get the following error:

```
Ld DerivedData/FinalTest/Build/Products/MonoMac/FinalTest.app/Contents/MacOS/FinalTest normal i386
    cd /Users/Admin/Projects/FinalTest/FinalTest/obj/Xcode/0
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.7
    /Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -L/Users/Admin/Projects/FinalTest/FinalTest/obj/Xcode/0/DerivedData/FinalTest/Build/Products/MonoMac -F/Users/Admin/Projects/FinalTest/FinalTest/obj/Xcode/0/DerivedData/FinalTest/Build/Products/MonoMac -filelist /Users/Admin/Projects/FinalTest/FinalTest/obj/Xcode/0/DerivedData/FinalTest/Build/Intermediates/FinalTest.build/MonoMac/FinalTest.build/Objects-normal/i386/FinalTest.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -framework Cocoa -framework Foundation -o /Users/Admin/Projects/FinalTest/FinalTest/obj/Xcode/0/DerivedData/FinalTest/Build/Products/MonoMac/FinalTest.app/Contents/MacOS/FinalTest

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
```

I am trying to build a MonoMac project.

Comment: Why aren't you building the project in MonoDevelop?

Comment: i am a c# devolper and want to develop app using c# the only way is to use mono develop

Comment: What is your version of Mac OS X ?

Answer (score 2):

The projects generated by MonoDevelop for Xcode are not meant to compile. They are only meant for editing the .xib files.